# gradle clean fails with "GradleException: Failed to create Jar file"

Tags: java, gradle

I'm seeing a very strange problem with gradle.

When I run any command (see clean below), gradle fails with a concurrent exception.

This is happening since my latest changes.  Rolling back to a previous commit works fine.

The changes are too numerous to describe here but in summary I've restructured the build a bit, based on another project which is working.  And when I say based on, I mean I have simply copied build.gradle, settings.gradle and gradle.properties from that other project.  None of the changes relate to jackson core.

```
$ ./gradlew clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'myservice'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\jars-9\b868ab677410c01cf9b5a0e29a035e73\jackson-core-2.15.2.jar.
    
BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

I tried removing the lock file but that failed:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/jars-9/*lock
rm: cannot remove '/c/Users/me/.gradle/caches/jars-9/jars-9.lock': Device or resource busy
```

So I ran `./gradlew --stop` which stopped 2 daemons, and I was able to remove the lock file.  But the `clean` still fails with the same error.

I've tried cleaning the `.gradle` directory in the project, and I've also tried checking out a new copy of the project.  Same result.

So although it seems like a cache error, I can fix it by rolling back to a previous commit (without touching the cache) and if I clear the cache, that doesn't fix it.

What's going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: The error you're encountering appears to be related to a problem with the Gradle cache and the creation of a JAR file for the Jackson Core library. This kind of issue can sometimes occur due to file system conflicts or corruption in the Gradle cache. To resolve that issue: Clean Gradle Cache, Clear Gradle Caches, Update Gradle and Plugins, Check for Third-Party Dependencies.

Comment: @AnisRafid I thought it might be the gradle cache.  But I cleaned both the project-level cache and the user-level cache, and it still fails.  When I switch to the previous commit, it works fine (even though it's using the same cache).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer was to do with [a bug in gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/24390).  Versions prior to 7.6.2 (?) failed to handle multi-release jar files (ie with multiple binaries built with different Java versions in them).

The jackson dependency was such a jar file.  This explains why the previous commit worked consistently, and this one failed consistently.  The project from which I copied the config uses gradle 8.1, which is why it worked there.

Solution: upgrade gradle.

Comment: This issue is finally resolved in version 8.4. So upgrade to 8.4 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

**Error message**

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file
> /Users/johnsmith/.gradle/caches/jars-9/b434e5cc9816519e3d9b77bd3c65f31a/jackson-core-2.16.0.jar

Upgrading to gradle 8.5 version using terminal solved my issue.